# capturing escape sequences from the output of a shell in python

Tags: python, shell, terminal, ansi-escape

I'm trying to create a Linux terminal in Python. but i know there's gonna be escape sequences sent by the shell and gonna need to interpret them, how can i capture the escape sequences and the control codes from the output of the shell and know their position? As an example this: `b'\x1b]0alaa@alaa-hplaptop15bs1xx:~/terminal\x07'`

Comment: q is not totally clear, just info: on unix `infocmp $TERM` can display escape sequences with their terminfo/termcap descriptions

Comment: as i said in my question i need to capture the escape sequences from the output of the shell

Comment: shell prompt ($PS1 for example) goes to stderr, so that capture stderr and you have them there

Comment: i redirected the std input/output/err to a psudoterminal

Comment: "i need to capture the escape sequences. i redirected the std input/output/err" so that if you done that properly, then captured escape sequences from stderr are there where they're redirected

Comment: for example `p=subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-i'], input=b'exit\n', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` then `p.stderr.decode()` will display stderr including caught escape sequences